# scrot (screenshot) cron job not executing

Tags: cron, screenshot

I'm trying to execute a `cron` job with **Scrot** (screenshot utility) but it won't work.

At first I thought it was a directory problem. I wrote `my.png` by itself at first, which could have been dropping it anywhere. So I changed the command to use the absolute paths. Since I've defined absolute paths, it seems like it would have to work correctly, but it's not. If I try to execute this as written on the command line, it works.

```
32 8,14,16 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/scrot /home/johndoe/my.png
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note that the times are not the problem, I keep putting it one or two minutes ahead of the current system time to test, and for other commands, it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the line in your `crontab` to this:

```
32 8,14,16 * * 1-5 DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/scrot /home/johndoe/my.png
```

Comment: Great! Glad it worked. Please consider marking the answer [as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) to help clean up and clarify the site's contents.

Comment: I added this line in crontab not working, can someone find what is the problem * * * * *  1-5 DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/scrot /home/mani/$(date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d%H%M").png . But works in command line.